# How do I delete the extra code SharePoint Designer Adds?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a html file that I would like to display in a Page Viewer Webpart.  I've found that there is an error with it rendering due to it being "unghosted."  SharePoint Designer automatically adds this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">FE5ZUCE7FNV6-132-3</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">50f71a31-b527-4736b30f-031637ae1e85</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">https://...aspx?ID=FE5ZUCE7FNV6-132-3, FE5ZUCE7FNV6-132-3</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
```

Research yielded a few options to get rid of the extra code.. Which included using Explorer view to drop the files into the library versus the form upload (did not work).  And the rest of the options seem to mention changing the settings to disable advanced mode in SPD (which we all need for customization so this isn't really an option);  or adding some asp code, but this seemed to be for Page Layouts instead of simple html files.  Does anyone know a fix to this issue or workaround?  And if so, can you please be precise in detailing what needs to be done?  IE.. "Add this to file in  tag.." etc.   I am really perturbed since there are other custom html files within the site collection and none seem to have this extra content added.

Thanks in advance for all help and/or suggestions.